# Pegar texto entre duas palavras com regex

Tags: php, regex

Gostaria de uma luz para meu problema. Meu objetivo é pegar a lista abaixo, dividindo os blocos entre as palavras `LOREM` e `LOREM` mas não quero pegar o texto todo que segue ao final do padrão da lista, como segue exemplo:

```
LOREM : 10505050
IPSUM : 1050051051084
DOLOR : 2620620620652
AMETI : 54084840540540
LOREM : 10505050
IPSUM : 1050051051084
DOLOR : 2620620620652
AMETI : 54084840540540
LOREM : 10505050
IPSUM : 1050051051084
DOLOR : 2620620620652
AMETI : 54084840540540
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

Estou utilizando esse regex: `/(?=LOREM :).+?(?:(?=LOREM :))/s`
Estou conseguindo selecionar todos, porém o último bloco de texto não consigo selecionar.

Para melhor entender segue esse exemplo: https://regex101.com/r/gM2fF1/1

Comment: Você quer pegar todas as ocorrências de `LOREM : número` e `Lorem seguindo de qualquer coisa`(esse é o ultimo bloco que não consegue capturar) ?

Comment: @perdeu Isso. Eu não consigo capturar o ultimo bloco. O único porém, é que tem vezes que alguns não vêm apenas com números.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro duas abordagens:

**#1: Por passos**

Podia dividir esse texto na "parte interessante" e deitar fora o resto usando [por exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/lV7iV1/1) `([^\.]+[\d]+)`.

Aí ia ficar somente com o padrão `chave : valor` e podia fazer um match mais simples que daria uma array com cada linha. [Algo como isto](http://ideone.com/SbobsM):

```
$regex = '(([\w]+) : ([\d]+))';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
```

**#2: Regex que agrupa captura**

Podia ter uma regex que captura diretamente grupos, isso implica que o seu padrão de grupos seja consistente. Uma [sugestão é fazer assim](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/y43n-fvjb):

```
$regex = '(([\w]+ : [\d]+[\s\n\r]){4})';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
```

Comment: Sergio, o segundo passo não me auxiliaria, pois não sei exatamente quantas linhas possui cada grupo. Tem vezes que varia de 4 a 5. Porém utilizei o primeiro passo e depois separei os grupos pelo `LOREM`. Ai foi. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @DiegoHenrique ok, ótimo que pude ajudar!

Answer (score 0):

1 - Use strlen

Ela retorna o comprimento de um texto passado como argumento. Exemplo de uso da função strlen:

```
<?php
    /*string strlen (string entrada)*/
    $qtd_char = strlen("Linha");
    echo $qtd_char;
?>
```

**O valor exibido será “6”, pois o texto “Linha de Código” contém seis caracteres.*

2 º Com a quantidade de texto adquirida use o **Substr**.

O substr é responsável por retornar um pedaço da string. Para isto ele se utiliza de três parâmetros: a própria string, o índice inicial e a quantidade de caracteres a ser retornada.

Acontece que podemos utilizar também um índice negativo, desta forma o PHP analisa a string contando N caracteres a partir do final, e não a partir do início. Veja a seguir alguns exemplos:

```
<?php

$texto = "eu não sou besta pra tirar onda de herói";

echo substr($texto, 0, $qtd_char);  // eu não sou besta

?>
```

Também podemos utilizar a substr() em combinação com a strpos(). A strpos detecta a posição que uma string ocorre dentro de uma expressão.

Comment: Mas o problema é que o tamanho do texto é variado, não tenho como saber ao certo.

Comment: Atualizei, Diego.